# channel numbering with xml coding

Tags: xml

I am using the code below to put channel numbers with my channel names on my freeview box, but because the coding does not have columns it looks kind of like this:

```
|    101  bbc one
|    102   bbc two
|    103  itv
|    104   channel 4
```

the start of the channel name is determined by the width of the channel number. How would I edit my code so all my channels line up like this:

```
|    101  bbc one
|    102  bbc two
|    103  itv
|    104  channel 4
```

this is my code:

```
for number in customised["video"].keys():
customised["video"][number]["number"] = number

# swap channel numbers. Only swaps number. Channel swap is still done in bouquetwriter.py

       if 
providerConfig.isSwapChannels() and "swapchannels" in providers[section_identifier] and len(providers[section_identifier]["swapchannels"]) > 0 and "preferred_order" in providers[section_identifier]["swapchannels"][0]:

for swaprule in providers[section_identifier]["swapchannels"][0]["preferred_order"]:

       if 
swaprule[0] in services[section_identifier]["video"] and swaprule[1] in services[section_identifier]["video"] and services[section_identifier]["video"][swaprule[1]]["service_type"] >= 17:

customised["video"][swaprule[0]]["number"] = swaprule[1]
customised["video"][swaprule[1]]["number"] = swaprule[0]


for service in sorted(customised["video"].keys()):

       if 
service in range(1,2000):

       if 
"interactive_name" in customised["video"][service]:
customised["video"][service]["interactive_name"] = " " * 5 + str(customised["video"][service]["number"]) + " " * 4 + customised["video"][service]["interactive_name"]

     else:
customised["video"][service]["interactive_name"] = " " * 5 + str(customised["video"][service]["number"]) + " " * 4 + customised["video"][service]["service_name"]
```

Comment: is that better?

Comment: No, not enough.
You also need to add more examples of the data - there appear to be at least 3 keys under `customised["video"][service]`, and nothing in your data example shows where those come from.
Your question was about how to handle the extra spaces after the channel numbers.  I answered that, I think.  
Your code has othing to do with your question, from what I can tell.

Comment: No not handle the spaces align the text after the second set of spaces

Comment: Your example only changes the first set of spaces, not the second (for those that have more than 1 - channel 103 only has one space.

Comment: The first set of spaces are before the number to bring it away from the edge of the screen and the second are between number and channel

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what your setup is, but assuming the first channel list is in a file named 'channels.txt', something like this might help:

```
with open('channels.txt', 'r') as fh:
    channels = dict([ line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in fh.readlines() ])
```

`channels` now looks like this:

```
{'102': 'bbc two', '103': 'itv', '101': 'bbc one', '104': ' channel 4'}
```

I can't tell how you want to build `customized`, but this seems like part of what you want.

Comment: This may be a bit clearer the bits i have in caps are what are shown on my screen                                                                                                 if "interactive_name" in customised["video"][service]:
            customised["video"][service]["interactive_name"] = " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + str(customised["video"][service]["NUMBERr"]) + " " + " " + " " + "  " + customised["video"][service]["CHANNEL NAME"]

Comment: You haven't provided enough  information to build the structure implied by the way you're indexing `customized`.

Comment: i have added more of my code to the origional question does this help, sorry if i am being hard work i am a bit of a novice lol

Comment: Please fix the formatting.  I can't make sense of it as-is

Answer (score 0):

Your question is now different than before.
Again, assuming what you want is in a file called `channels.txt`, the following code will rewrite it to the format you want:

```
with open('channels.txt', 'r') as fh:
    channels = '\n'.join([ '{} {:>5}  {}'.format(*line.strip().split(None, 2))
                           for line in fh.read().split('\n') ])

with open('channels.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(channels)
```